# Random Landing Page (Vue / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to show a different .vue file when the visitor refreshes the Home page.

Right now I have one page called Home.vue
I'm trying to load Home1.vue Home2.vue randomly on every refresh.

```
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: () => import('./views/Home.vue')
},
```

Maybe I have have one "homepage" but the whole content/template can be loaded randomly.

Can someone figure out how to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import function takes the path as the string may this will help you

```
const pages = ['home.vue', 'about.vue', 'third.vue']
import(`./views/${pages[Math.floor(Math.random()*pages.length)]}`)
```

Good luck!